# Подсказки Intellisense в Visual Studio на русском языке

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Начинаю изучать C#, работая в Visual Studio.

Вижу, что есть удобные контекстные подсказки, но они только на английском.

По гайдам в интернете не удалось найти, как изменить язык на русский (и возможно ли это вовсе), ибо вся информация для Visual Studio Code, а не для просто Visual Studio.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть!

Comment: Лучше привыкать к английскому.

Comment: Поддерживаю вышенаписанное. Русский нужен разве что с коллегами общаться, да в 1С прогать. В разработке - english must have. Потыкаешься, попереводишь, хоть как-то будешь знать что написано. А то точно так же ошибки ЯП будут на английском, а ты сидишь с большими глазами и не понимаешь.  А так - прочитал, открыл переводчик один раз, другой, запомнил и уже в след. раз вполне знаешь что делать